# Make Alias exempt from RewriteRule

Tags: apache2

I have the following Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    Alias "/.well-known" "/var/www/example.com/.well-known"

    RewriteEngine On

    <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example.com'">
        RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    </If>

    <ElseIf "%{HTTPS} != 'on'">
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    </ElseIf>

</VirtualHost>
```

I want the `Alias` exempt from the HTTPS redirect, i.e. `http://example.com/.well-known/x` should return the file at `/var/www/example.com/.well-known/x`. At the moment it is redirecting to HTTPS per the `RewriteRules` below.

How can I make the `Alias` exempt from the redirect?

Answer (score 1):

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example.com' && !(${REQUEST_URI -strcmatch '/.well-known/*')" >
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</If>

<ElseIf "%{HTTPS} != 'on' && !(${REQUEST_URI -strcmatch '/.well-known/*')">
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</ElseIf>
```

Comment: Thanks, yep that's what I'm using actually but I thought there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: If there was, I wouldn't know it. Sorry.